# A word for "in case of"

Tags: single-word-requests

In many disciplines, there is the frequent need to express, with as few words as possible, that, e.g., a method, model, or principle ***X*** is effective or relevant if a specific situation, status, or occurence ***B*** arises.

To this end, in English, we could use "A ***in case of*** B", which, however, consists of three words.

I thought about "provided", however, it puts emphasis on what "would" be the necessary condition (degree of uncertainty), which does not fit the context.

An example sentence would be: "This is the procedure **in case of** missing material".

Comment: @All: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: I'll not put forward the synonym 'given' in an answer as it's ambiguous and far less likely to be used than the original. But 'This is the procedure given a breakdown in the negotiations' works.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a single word for this. "in case of" is already short, why do you need a single word?

Comment: You might try putting a comma before “given”. That makes it clear. I would have offered “ , given “ as an answer but, despite @AndrewLeach’s admonition, it too often happens that suggestions dealing only partly with an answer attract adverse comment and reaction. And such clearly would be the case here, where “given” has been ruled out by other comment.

Comment: @barmar It is for a presentation heading. So what I actually want to write is "Procedure in case of missing material", but with one word for "in case of" ;)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you're saying that "given missing material" works? Is "given" not entirely equivalent to "provided"? Would provided therefore also work?

Comment: I don't think it's common to shorten this. If there were, it would probably be used on signage like "In case of fire".

Comment: Not really, and no, Sebastian. 'Given' is, unlike 'provided', used as a short form of 'given that there is' (but the shortening can be inappropriate in some sentences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the word regarding.

"This is the procedure regarding missing material"

Regarding: "In reference to; with respect to; concerning."
https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=regarding+definition&ia=definition

Answer (score 5):

**for**

This is the procedure for missing material.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for):

> with the object or purpose of:
> *to run for exercise.*

Comment: "for missing material" doesn't seem right to me. The purpose isn't to cause material to go missing.

Comment: @Barmar - Maybe that was too succinct.  How's this?  *for handling missing material.*

Comment: yes, that makes more sense

Comment: Perhaps "regarding missing material" would be better?

Comment: @Steve - that could work too.  I guess it depends on your audience -- whether you want down to earth, or formal.

Comment: @Steve I actually like regarding, why don't you make an answer?

Answer (score 1):

"when" seems to fit, although it sounds better if we flip the object of the preposition into a statement rather than a gerund.

> This is the procedure when material is missing.

Comment: Or retain the word order, use a comma and say simply “, when missing material”. Alternatively “, whenever missing material”.

Answer (score 1):

Although another word is changed, this construction reflects what I think you're trying to say.

This is the procedure absent suggested (pick your adjective) material.

Answer (score 1):

'Lest' seems to cover it. Sentence should read 'This is the procedure to follow lest material goes missing'. Not a good example. Do a search here for various uses of 'lest'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something short, I suggest **re**.

Some people might consider it business jargon or officialese, and claim it is not suitable for literary English, but sources say it is widely used in formal documents. It is a Latin word imported into English in business and administrative contexts precisely to fill the need for a short term meaning "concerning" or "with regard to".

Example: "This is the procedure re material."

**re** in this sense is defined in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/re) as "about; concerning".

They offer the usage note:

> The traditional view is that re should be used in headings and references, as in Re: Ainsworth versus Chambers, but not as a normal word meaning ‘about’, as in I saw the deputy head re the incident. However, the evidence suggests that re is now widely used in the second context in official and semi-official contexts, and is now generally accepted. It is hard to see any compelling logical argument against using it as an ordinary English word in this way